# Filter across 2 lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists:

```
a. requestedAmenities 
b. units with amenities.
```

I want to filter those units that have any one of the "requested amenities". 
I have tried to achieve the same result using `foreach` loops but I believe it should be much easier using LINQ. Can someone please help\advice?

```
UnitAmenities unitSearchRequestAmenities = unitSearchRequest.Amenities;

var exactMatchApartmentsFilteredByAmenities= new Units();
IEnumerable<string> requestAmenitiesIds =  unitSearchRequestAmenities.Select(element => element.ID);
foreach (var unitCounter in ExactMatchApartments)
{
    IEnumerable<string> unitAmenities = unitCounter.Amenities.Select(element => element.ID);

    foreach (var requestAmenityId in requestAmenitiesIds)
    {
        foreach (var unitAmenity in unitAmenities)
        {
            if (requestAmenityId == unitAmenity)
            {
                exactMatchApartmentsFilteredByAmenities.Add(unitCounter);
                //break to the outmost foreach loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the Except function

Comment: I think you mean `Intersect` not `Except`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter based on compliance with an Intersect rule

```
var matchedAmenities = ExactMatchApartments.Where(ema => ema.Amenities
                                               .Any(x => unitSearchRequestAmenities
                                                   .Count(y => y.ID == x.ID) == 1));
exactMatchApartmentsFilteredByAmenities.AddRange(matchedAmenities);
```

This is a somewhat "custom" `Intersect` given that the default LINQ `Intersect` extension doesn't support lambda expressions.

Comment: Thanks Jason. This should work. I will test this tomorrow and update.

Comment: It looks a little bit off too me, but I just can't put my finger on the reason why.

Comment: Instead of using Count(...) > 0, use the Any method.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Yuriy. I have tested the LINQ query above and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your types, but I think the following should do the trick

```
from unit in ExactMatchApartments
from amenity in unit.Amenities
join requestedAmenity in unitSearchRequestAmenities
on amenity.ID equals requestedAmenity.ID
select unit
```

This is a case where a query expression is both easier to read and understand as opposed to dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason, I believe it must be Intersect not Except.I have changed the code to the following:

```
var amenities = unitSearchRequest.Amenities;
if (amenities.Count > 0)
{
    //filter the unit's amenities's id's with the search request amenities's ID's.
    var exactMatchApartmentsFilteredByAmenities= new Units();
    var requestAmenitiesIds = amenities.Select(element => element.ID);
    foreach (var unitCounter in ExactMatchApartments)
    {
        var unitAmenities = unitCounter.Amenities.Select(element => element.ID);
        var intersect    =unitAmenities.Intersect(requestAmenitiesIds);
        if (intersect.Any())
        {
            exactMatchApartmentsFilteredByAmenities.Add(unitCounter);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I will test the code and update here my results.